# Python: Save tiff-File in Excel

Tags: python, excel, image, tiff

I am using openpyxl but if i want to save my greyscale tiff-image, the following error occurs:
"OSError: cannot write mode F as PNG"

I read it with the library pillow but when I apply .convert('L') and save it to a file, the image brightness changes in comparison to when I open it in Irfanview.

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open(file_path).convert("L").save(output_file_path)
```

Any ideas?